# Using HW1F Trinomial Tree for backwards-looking RFR

Tags: interest-rates

I have built a hull-white trinomial tree following [this famous paper](http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/%7Ehull/downloadablepublications/Generalized%20HW%20model%20and%20Super%20Calibration.pdf). Now this was built in the LIBOR forward-looking space. I wonder if the same can be used for a backwards-looking rate (such as USD SOFR)?

Specifically, I believe there would minimal/no change to the treatment except perhaps:

1. Instead of simulating the 3m-LIBOR, we use a historical 3m SOFR compounded rate(?) Using SOFR rate directly should be possible as well.
2. Using (i)th node's r*t to discount the payoff from (i)th to (i-1)th node.

Any idea/links would be much appreciated.